# Python program issue run at bootup, just work one time

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, python-3, google-chrome

I have some problem on Rpi3. I work for kiosk program. I created python script. If rpi connect to internet, chrome shows page from internet but if there is not internet connection on pi, chrome shows the page I previously saved(page.html).

I created python script for this. I added this python script `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file with this way `@/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/check.py`. My python script works good if you run manually. Script should control internet connection every ten second and it makes doing the above operations. When reboot rpi, chrome launches page correctly one time after that python script does not doing anything. It does not doing control internet connection or not start new tab. But manually work correct. I tried `chmod +x` but it did not work. Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import requests
import os
import webbrowser
import time

url='www.google.com'
url2='/home/pi/Downloads/page.html'
netflg=True

def internet_on():
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
            netflg=True
            print(netflg)
            chrome_path='/usr/bin/chromium-browser %s' 
            webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
            loop()
            return True

        except:
            netflg=False
            print(netflg)
            chrome_path='/usr/bin/chromium-browser %s'
            webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url2)
            loop()
            return False

def loop():
    time.sleep(10)
    internet_on()

internet_on()
```

How can i fix this wrong?

Comment: recursive loops are a recipe for disaster!

Answer (score 1):

Is the script still alive after it opens Chrome on boot? Do a `ps aux` to check, my guess it that a `webbrowser.Error` was raised by either `get` or `open` while in the `except:` block and the script simply failed.

You could add some logging or [redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python), if once you run the script with autostart you can't simply see the output anymore.

In addition to this, I'd recommend against calling loop() and internet_on() inside each other, it's better if you make a single method with things happening in that  single big `while TRUE:` loop.

Comment: Yes I controlled my python script with `ps aux | grep script.py`. It is alive.

Comment: Time to add some logging to understand what's happening, it could be looping in except: forever generating exceptions continuously.